# Multi Party ECDSA?

Tags: transactions, security, cryptography, encryption

Are there any alternatives to the Multi Part ECDSA implementation contributed by [ZenGo](http://github.com/ZenGo-X/multi-party-ecdsa)?

Answer (score 1):

I know about this one by Binance but haven't tried it myself and don't know if it's been audited:

https://github.com/binance-chain/tss-lib

Comment: Interesting, both ZenGo & Binance seem to have been audited by the same firm (Kudelski Security)